# Loggers to Multiple Appenders at Different Thresholds by Logger

Tags: java, log4j

I have two appenders.  One is attached to the console and one is to a log file.  But that's not really that important.  The issue I have is I want everything to go to the file at INFO level.  The console is different however. There a bunch of loggers I don't want touching the console at WARN or INFO level because they spray a lot more information than the user needs.

So lets say I have three loggers A, B, C.  A, B, and C should all go to the file appenders at INFO level.  A should go to the console for INFO, B should go to the console for WARN and C should go to the console for ERROR.  What does a log4j config to do this look like?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/app.log" filePattern="logs/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz"
                 ignoreExceptions="false">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    </RollingFile>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT" ignoreExceptions="false">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n"/>
    </Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="A" level="trace" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" level="info" />
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" level="info"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="B" level="trace" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" level="warn" />
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" level="info"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="C" level="trace" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" level="error" />
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" level="info"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" level="trace" />
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" level="trace"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Comment: assuming that you're using log4j2